# 404 error Localhost:8000 asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net5

If I un-comment the `app.Run(async (context) => ...` part of the code I can run the html within the code without any issues. I am trying to use the index.html in wwwroot to be default. But I get a 404 error. How do I fix this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace TheWorld
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to  configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {

          //  app.Run(async (context) =>
          //{
          //    var link = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
          //   <html>
          //      <head>
          //      <title>test</title>
          //      </head>
          //      <body>
          //          <h1>TestFile</h1>
          //      </body>
          //    </html>";
          //    await context.Response.WriteAsync(link);
          //});
        }


        // Entry point for the application.
        public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>    (args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Nuget-package `Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles` and then the first thing in your `Configure` write something like this:

```
    app.UseDefaultFiles(new DefaultFilesOptions
    {
        DefaultFileNames = new List<string>() { "index.html" }
    });
```